# What is the bash '<(file contents)' syntax called?

Tags: bash, file-descriptors

This [answer on Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58077/generating-ecdsa-certificate-and-private-key-in-one-step) uses an interesting bash syntax to generate a file in-line:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -newkey ec:<(openssl ecparam -name secp384r1) -keyout cert.key -out cert.crt -days 3650
```

This bit is particularly interesting:

```
<(openssl ecparam -name secp384r1)
```

Running just:

```
echo <(openssl ecparam -name secp384r1)
```

I get back `/dev/fd/63`

So this seems to make a temporary file descriptor with the file's contents.

**What is this called?**

Comment: Note that the resulting "file" is actually a named pipe, and some programs don't support them as file arguments. Example: `git diff --no-index file1 <(cat file2)` will fail with: `error: /dev/fd/63: unsupported file type`. You might also see `error: readlink("/dev/fd/63"): No such file or directory` if the implementation creates a symlink to the pipe (appears as a broken link for me for some reason).

Comment: Related: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216) and [What does a “< <(…)” redirection mean?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/22645/80216)

Answer (score 37):

It's called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) and is a feature of bash, zsh and ksh (and possibly others, I don't know). It isn't POSIX and you shouldn't use it in portable code, but it's very useful.

Here's the relevant section of the bash manual:

> 3.5.6 Process Substitution
>
> Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes
> (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files. It takes the form
> of
>
> ```
>   <(list)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>   >(list)
> ```
>
> The process list is run with its input or output connected to a FIFO or some file in /dev/fd. The name of this file is passed as an
> argument to the current command as the result of the expansion.
> If the >(list) form is used, writing to the file will provide input for list. If the <(list) form is used, the file passed as an argument should be
> read to obtain the output of list. Note that no space may appear
> between the < or > and the left parenthesis, otherwise the construct
> would be interpreted as a redirection.
>
> When available, process substitution is performed simultaneously with
> parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic
> expansion.