# Write shell script to analysis log file

Tags: shell-script

The log file is as below:-

```
Source=Mobile
IP=189.23.45.01
STATUS=SUCCESS
TIME=10 sec

Source=Desktop
IP=189.23.34.23
STATUS=FAIL
TIME=101 sec

Source=Mobile
IP=189.23.34.23
STATUS=FAIL
TIME=29 sec
```

File keep going so on.

Questions:

1. Find IP where status is FAIL?
2. Find Ave time taken by all request where status is "success"?
3. List how many logins were via Mobile and how much time did it took ?

Comment: If the entries of the log are consistent (four lines, third being status), then you can list only the failed ones by utilising `grep`s context line controls. e.g. `grep -B2 -A1 STATUS=FAIL`

Comment: @Machine Could you please clarify what you mean with "...and how much time did it took"? Do you want to know the overall time involved in Mobile-logins, successful and failed? An average? A overal or average calculation for only successful or only failed mobile logins?

Answer (score 1):

In an unpolished version, a Bash-script could look like this, assuming that your data is contained in `datafile`:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "IPs where status is fail:\n"
grep -z -oP 'IP=\K.*\n(?=STATUS=FAIL)' datafile

printf "Avg time taken by all requests where status is 'success':\n"
grep -z -oP 'STATUS=SUCCESS\nTIME=\K\d+' datafile | \
  awk '{ total += $1; count++ } END { print ( count == 0 ? "NaN" : total/count); }'

printf "Number of logins (successful and failed) via Mobile:\n"
grep -c 'Source=Mobile' datafile
```

A brief elucidation:

- Q2) Calculation of the Average time: the `grep` command extracts the time values (which are assumed to be all in seconds). These values are piped into the `awk` command, which calculates their average, and then prints that average.

Comment: @Machine What did you mean with "...and how time did they sent" ?

Comment: can u explain what exactly u doing in second command to find Avg?

Comment: @Machine Of course, if you elucidate your question :-)

Comment: @steeldriver Sorry. It seems I spoiled the fun... Perhaps we should leave it to Machine to figure out what the commands do precisely. Specific questions will be answered then...

Answer (score 1):

You're really asking 3 questions - I'll get you started with the first one, and you should make an effort to solve the other two yourself using the same basic structure (there are plenty of examples on this site for using Awk to do numerical processing such as averaging):

Use Awk in *paragraph mode* (by unsetting the record separator, `RS`), splitting the record into fields using `=` and `\n` (newline):

```
$ awk -vRS= -F'[=\n]' '/STATUS=FAIL/{print $4}' file.log
189.23.34.23
189.23.34.23
```

Comment: @Steekdriver, i need your help to understanding what u meant by unsetting the record separator, RS.

Comment: @Machine see for example [4.9 Multiple-Line Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-record-separators_002c-with-multiline-records) in the GNU Awk User's Guide

Comment: @Steekdriver - awk -vRS= -F'[=\n]' '/STATUS=FAIL/ sum+=$8 {print sum}' test.log  
When doing this , i get error as below  awk: /STATUS=FAIL/ sum+=$8 {print sum}
awk:                  ^ syntax error

Comment: @Steekdriver , below is what i get when i run :                                                          awk -F '=\n' '{/Source=Mobile/a[$2] += $8} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' test.log
awk: {/Source=Mobile/a[$2] += $8} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}
awk:                       ^ syntax error

Comment: @Machine you seem to be misunderstanding the basic rule-action structure of Awk progams - have a look at the examples [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Very-Simple)

Comment: n=0;while read i;do n=$((n+i));done < <(awk -vRS=  -F '[=\n]' '/Source=Mobile/ {print $8}' test.log);echo "MOBILE:-"$n;
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: @Steekdriver, any hints you can throw ?

Comment: Comments really aren't appropriate for this. It looks like you are trying to use *process substitution* in a shell that doesn't support it - see [What is the bash '<(file contents)' syntax called?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294636/65304)

Comment: Wow!!! Grt , Thanks a lot . This worked in Bash .                                                                                       **n=0;while read i;do n=$((n+i));done < <(awk -vRS=  -F '[=\n]' '/Source=Mobile/ {print $8}' test.log);echo "MOBILE:-"$n;**
MOBILE:-39

Answer (score -2):

```
read -p "Lets Give File Name , placed in the same dir: " file ; 
echo " Ques : Find the Number of IP which failed "
echo "Ans: "

cat "${file}".txt | grep -i STATUS=FAIL -B1 | grep -i IP | awk -F '=' '{print $NF}'
#cat "${file}".txt | grep -i STATUS=SUCCESS -A1 | grep -i Time | awk -F '=' '{print $NF}' &> clear2.txt

echo "Ques : Find the avg of success time"
echo "Ans : "

cat "${file}".txt | grep -i STATUS=SUCCESS -A1 | grep -i Time | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' &> clear2.txt
avgtime=0
i=0
for x in `cat clear2.txt`
do  
    i=$(($i + 1))
    avgtime=$(($avgtime +$x))
    echo "avg time after ${i} iteration is :${avgtime}"
    y=$(($x))
done
#echo "${x}"
#echo "${y}"
avgtime=$(($avgtime/$i))

echo "THe avg time is : ${avgtime}"

echo "Ques : What is the Number of time mobile was tried to login"

echo "Ans :"

cat testfile.txt | grep -i Mobile | wc -l
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please keep in mind, though, that [using shell loops for text processing is discouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) as it is very inefficient when compared to standard Unix/Linux tools such as `awk`.