# awk code explanation

Tags: awk

I've been given some code that is supposed to be working, but it doesn't, and i'm trying to understand why that is. I'm trying to learn bash and awk for that reason, but it's quite confusing to me. If someone could help me to understand this awk code I would be really happy.

`cvgMids.txt` contains many lines of the following format

```
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11b74p1stp>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.type>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/cvg.video_game_soundtrack>  .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11bc4msmrn>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.type>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/cvg.cvg_developer>  .
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11bxxz28q6>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.type>   <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/cvg.computer_videogame> .
```

- What is the point of `BEGIN{i=0;}` I don't see variable i being used in any of the following lines.
- What is `<(cat cvgMids.txt) <(gzip -dc freebase-rdf-latest.gz) > cvg_predicates.txt` for? I get that you put the files in the end of awk but it's confusing to me with all these parenthesis etc.

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0;}
FNR == NR {
    if($1 in a) next;
    a[$1] = $1;
    next
}
FNR<NR {
    if($1 in a) {print $0;}}' <(cat cvgMids.txt) <(gzip -dc freebase-rdf-latest.gz) > cvg_predicates.txt
```

Comment: What is the code *intended* to do, and in what way is it failing? it seems to have been written by someone who has little experience with awk

Comment: "Everytime $1 contains the whole line" ... It would contain the first column. Unless the FS is set to something non-default (and I don't see that), it won't contain the whole line.

Comment: after a[$1] = $1; i added a print a[$1]; and the whole line is being printed

Comment: And as for the `<()`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294635/what-is-the-bash-file-contents-syntax-called/294636#294636

Comment: If you meant `print a[$1];` no, it doesn't - not for me - I get the first column as expected.

Comment: @steeldriver I believe it's purpose is to get the first column "for example <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/g.11b74p1stp>" and use it to fetch all lines from freebase-rdf-latest.gz that contain it.

Comment: You are right muru i must have made a mistake. It does print the first column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the snippet appears to do is output the lines from the uncompressed contents of `freebase-rdf-latest.gz` whose first whitespace-delimited field `$1` matches any of the first whitespace-delimited fields from `cvgMids.txt`. However it could be written more simply.

In particular:

- as you noted, `i` is not used anywhere so the `BEGIN` block may be eliminated
- the sequence

  ```
  if($1 in a) next;
  a[$1] = $1;
  next
  ```

  could be reduced to

  ```
  a[$1];
  next
  ```

  (the array's *values* are never used, only its indices and it's almost certainly as efficient to re-assign the index multiple times as to test and conditionally assign it)
- in the rule-action

  ```
  FNR<NR {
      if($1 in a) {print $0;}}
  ```

  you don't really need `FNR<NR` since you've already dealt with the case `FNR==NR` and `FNR>NR` is not going to happen<sup>1</sup>. Also, `{print $0;}` is the default action. So it would be more idiomatic to write

  ```
  $1 in a
  ```
- `<(cat cvgMids.txt)` and  `<(gzip -dc freebase-rdf-latest.gz)` are shell *process substitutions*. Functionally, the first is equivalent to `cvgMids.txt` (it's both a [Useless Use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) and a useless use of redirection). Perhaps it was used for aesthetic reasons.

Putting it all together, we get

```
awk 'FNR == NR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' cvgMids.txt <(gzip -dc freebase-rdf-latest.gz) > cvg_predicates.txt
```

However, if the original is not working, the simplified version won't work either.

---

<sup>1</sup> unless your code modifies `FNR` and/or `NR` - which is legal, but rarely done in practice.

Comment: That was very very helpfull. Btw isn't > cvg_predicates.txt needed to output the matches to a new txt?

Comment: @profchaos oops sorry you are absolutely correct - will edit